# Change mouse cursor when entering/exiting Area2d

Tags: godot, gdscript

I have tried every google result that seems relevant and cannot find a solution to something I'm sure is simpler than I'm making it. There's a possibility all of the results are outdated, as the official documents don't seem to offer what I'm seeing in search result suggestions.

When the mouse enters an Area2D, I want the mouse cursor to change to the hand pointing cursor. When I exit the Area2D, I want it to change back to the pointer. I am not looking to use custom cursors, just the basic ones already implemented in GODOT.

I know how to use mouse_entered/mouse_exited signals. I just can't determine the correct code and location to make the change happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When the mouse enters an Area2D, I want the mouse cursor to change to the hand pointing cursor. When I exit the Area2D, I want it to change back to the pointer. I am not looking to use custom cursors, just the basic ones already implemented in GODOT.

For that, the functions you want are `Input.set_default_cursor_shape` and `Input.get_current_cursor_shape`.

> I know how to use mouse_entered/mouse_exited signals. I just can't determine the correct code and location to make the change happen.

You place the code in whatever signal handlers you connected. I remind you that you can connect the signals from the IDE in the "Node" panel, "Signals" tab. *And in the code, you should see a green icon next to the func is connected to a signal.* See also [Signals](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/step_by_step/signals.html).

For example, I connected them to a script in the same `Area2D`, and added this code:

```
func _on_Area2D_mouse_entered() -> void:
    Input.set_default_cursor_shape(Input.CURSOR_POINTING_HAND)

func _on_Area2D_mouse_exited() -> void:
    Input.set_default_cursor_shape(Input.CURSOR_ARROW)
```

Or if you want to store the previous `CursorShape`, you can do this:

```
var old_cursor_shape:int = Input.CURSOR_ARROW

func _on_Area2D_mouse_entered() -> void:
    old_cursor_shape = Input.get_current_cursor_shape()
    Input.set_default_cursor_shape(Input.CURSOR_POINTING_HAND)

func _on_Area2D_mouse_exited() -> void:
    Input.set_default_cursor_shape(old_cursor_shape)
```

See [`CursorShape`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.4/classes/class_input.html#enum-input-cursorshape) for the values. *Note: There seems to be a bug in the current beta that cause these to not autocomplete.*

---

**Reason why mouse_entered/mouse_exited might not work.**

*Assuming they are correctly connected.*

If there is any `Control` (for example a `Container` or a background) overlapping a `Node2D` - such as an `Area2D` - regardless if it is in front or behind visually. It will prevent it from taking the input. Thus, you must set its `mouse_filter` of the `Control` to `Ignore`.

And make sure the `collision_layer` and `collision_mask` of the `Area2D` are not empty (0), `input_pickable` is true, and of course the `Area2D` has a valid `CollisionShape2D` or `CollisionPolygon2D`. Otherwise mouse_entered/mouse_exited won't work.

*Also, I remind you to pay attention to any errors reported by the IDE.*

Answer (score 0):

One thing I recommend you can do would be to make an `Area2D` as a child of the root node (most likely a `Node2D`) rename the new `Area2D` to whatever you want (as long as it isn't named `Area2D`. For the sake of teaching you, I'm gonna rename it to CursorBox) and attach a script to that new `Area2D`. Add a `CollisionShape2D` node as a child of the `Area2D`, set the shape as a circle, and set the radius to 0.5. Next, go to the top right and press the node button. Connect "Area Entered' and "Area Exited" to the CursorBox. Inside of your script, make sure your functions look like what I have written below.

```
extends Area2D
var mouseCheck = false
func _on_CursorBox_area_entered(area):
    if area.name == ("Area2D"): #This `Area2D` its looking for would be the buttons Area2D
        mouseCheck = true
func _on_CursorBox_area_exited(area):
    if area.name == ("Area2D"):
        mouseCheck = false
```

The mouse check is just there to see if it works, obviously put your code in there, whatever you need to put in. I would imagine you have some animation you want to play or something. If you have any more questions, just reply and we'll see what else we can do to fix it.